# Do I need to load a loading scene which loads another scene?

Tags: screen, unity-game-engine, loading

So I have a question. I have a main scene which is like a map. When my character leaves the scene and collides with a certain object I usually load my other scene without having a loading screen. But now I have decided to make an loading screen. The "problem" is that after I leave my main scene I have to load the loading screen which after its loaded loads the other scene. Is there another to make a loading screen because to load the loading screen also takes time to load?

Comment: No, technically, you don't need a "loading scene". You can handle the asynchronous loading of your 2nd scene inside your map scene.

Comment: [LoadSceneAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) may help you if you still want a loading screen.

Comment: @ryemoss So basically do you mean that I should load my second scene in background while I am in my loading scene or should I load my loading screen in background while i am in my first scene?

Comment: either. or both. if you load your second scene in the first there would be no need for the loading screen as Hellium suggested.

Comment: @Hellium But what if I want a loading screen? Should I load the loading screen in my background while I am still in the first scene?

Comment: @ryemoss With a loading screen it looks more profesional. But if l load for example my loading screen in the background could the game lag till its done loading?

Comment: @KeyNavas I am not sure how LoadAsync handles resources, but I imagine that is a possibility, yes. I can't imagine a loading screen would have too many assets to cause much lag however (or even take a long time to load without loadasync).

Comment: loading scenes are very simple,it will load in a fraction of a second, so, load the loading scene from your 1st scene

Comment: @Lestat So I should load the loading scene in the background while i am in my first scene?

Comment: @KeyNavas : What I meant is, you don't need a **dedicated** scene. You could create a singleton class you can call anywhere you want, and this class would display a loading screen in order to load your next scene.

Comment: there are several ways of doing that

Comment: if the loading scene takes a long time to load then perhaps add a loading scene before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow may be different with different people. Here is the workflow I follow:

You must have a main menu scene with just UI that is used to load your first game scene. The reason for this to make sure that your app loads **very fast** and also so that it can pass the Google Play and Appstore test.

After the first time the app is loaded, you do not need to load that main menu scene again. What you do is to create a UI panel with `Text` and `Image` component that shows the status of the loading scene with [`AsyncOperation.progress`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743288/3785314).You can learn more about loading scenes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743288/3785314). You can enable or disable this UI panel with `gameObject.SetActive`. You also have to make sure that this UI GameObject does not destroy when new scene loads by adding `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);` to it.

Comment: So basically you mean when I load a new map/scene I enable the panel and after the map is loaded I disable/make it invisible. Do you also load some scenes in background? In order to access the loaded map "faster"/you dont have to load it at the end?

Comment: Yes, you enable the UI panel to show the loading status. After it is done loading, you disable the panel then activate the loaded scene. Yes, you load the scene in background with `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` so that you can see the status on the screen. *"In order to access the loaded map "faster"/you dont have to load it at the end?"* I don't understand that question

Comment: What I meant is that when you load a scene not in background it takes some time till the entire scene is loaded. At least that's what happens when I load a scene. If I load a scene in the background does the scene opens immidietly or can I deside when to enter the scene?

Comment: The idea of loading scene in the background is not to speed it up and does not mean it will speed it up. It's just that you can be able to do other things while the scene is loading. For example, showing some animation, or showing a loading screen that moves based on the load progress. This cannot be done if the scene is not loaded in the background.

Comment: Can I decide when to open the scene after I loaded it in the background?

Comment: Yes, check the link I put in my answer. It shows how to do that.

Comment: oooh alright thanks. In the example which is shown I only need to load all the scenes ONCE and then I can choose which to open? So I dont need always to load it?

Comment: That example shown is only meant to answer question in that question. I only linked it because it shows how load scene and activate it. You don't have to load all scenes as mentioned in that answer. It's just answer that question. Although, you can load scene in the background then activate/open it anytime you want.

Comment: Do not forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if this answered your question.